# OpenGL lighting works incorrectly on Android and WebAssembly

Tags: android, c++, qt, opengl-es, webassembly

I wrote an example that loads 3D model from DAE COLLADA using Qt 6. Source code: [load-3d-model-from-dae-opengl-window-qt6-cpp.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6t7gl99xcsxyfpt1mad6p/load-3d-model-from-dae-opengl-window-qt6-cpp.zip?rlkey=bk5t87kn6ljri8zqfhfhnll2c&dl=1)

OpenGL lighting works correctly on Desktop but incorrectly on Android and WebAssembly:

Desktop:

[image: d138eecf-d8bd-4de3-86aa-c7669484c12b-image.png]

Android:

[image: 094dc9ee-508f-4ba4-87c8-28c1444262ba-image.png]

WebAssembly:

[image: ef0b3e64-6deb-46ad-984b-9a9610509561-image.png]

**Added:**

I added this line of code `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);` to `OpenGLWindow::initializeGL()`. The problem was solved for a cube on Android:

[image]

and WebAssembly:

[image]

When I change a model with Mario it works on Desktop:

[image]

But it doesn't work for Android:

[image]

and WebAssembly:

[image]

Source code: [load-3d-model-from-dae-opengl-window-qt6-cpp.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6t7gl99xcsxyfpt1mad6p/load-3d-model-from-dae-opengl-window-qt6-cpp.zip?rlkey=bk5t87kn6ljri8zqfhfhnll2c&dl=1)

Cross-refs:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/154413/loading-3d-model-from-dae-collada-using-qt-6-opengl-lighting-works-incorrectly-on-android-and-webassembly
- https://community.khronos.org/t/loading-3d-model-from-dae-collada-using-qt-6-opengl-lighting-works-incorrectly-on-android-and-webassembly/110523

Comment: I created the bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-122145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to set a depth buffer size to 24:

```cpp
OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow()
{
    setTitle("OpenGL ES 2.0, Qt6, C++");
    resize(350, 350);

    QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat;
    surfaceFormat.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    setFormat(surfaceFormat);
}
```

It works on WebAssembly at least from Windows 10, 64-bit: https://65d340535ef3fa042a6d1ce3--charming-malabi-d8d124.netlify.app/

[image]

And on Redmi 4X, Android 7:

[image]